# How get the device name of bluetooth paired devices?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm having some troubles getting the name of bluetooth devices.

I'm connecting a bluetooth printer that has the name of `MTP-3` (this name is in hard code) , but I want to connect another bluetooth printer which has another name so I change the name of the second printer in the List of the Paired Devices of Operating System in the settings but It doesn't work.

Also, if I change the name of the first printer to something other than `MTP-3` the printer still connects with my app.

I'm looking for some method that gives me the exactly name of the paired devices with Android even if I change the name with the Opereting System.

```
  Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            if (pairedDevice.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice pairedDev : pairedDevice) {

    if(pairedDev.getName.equals("MTP-3")){
          bluetoothDevice = pairedDev;
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "found it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the returned set:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter =BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will get the bluetooth name, and if it doesn't have a name, it will return the address.

```
public String getDeviceName(){
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }
    String name = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
    if(name == null){
        System.out.println("Name is null!");
        name = mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
    }
    return name;
}
```